# How does SAS match columns in a set statement

Tags: dataset, sas

When we do this:

```
data test;
   set temp1 temp2;
run;
```

Does it match `temp1` and `temp2` by column names or column positions?

My guess is column names, but cannot find confirmation.

What happens if there is a column that exists in `temp1` and not in `temp2`?

Comment: Just a note that if you are appending tables it's faster to use Proc Append as it does not read the tables line by line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By name.  Columns not on both tables exist on the output tables but with missing values for rows coming from the source table where they don't exist.  This is super easy to test.

```
data d1;
    input var1 $ var2 $ var3;
    datalines;
e j 1
e k 2
e l 3
;
run;

data d2;
    input var2 $ var1 $ var5;
    datalines;
e j 1
e k 2
e l 3
;
run;

data d3;
    set d1 d2;
run;

proc print data=d3;
run;
```

Result:

```
Obs var1 var2 var3 var5

 1   e    j     1    . 
 2   e    k     2    . 
 3   e    l     3    . 
 4   j    e     .    1 
 5   k    e     .    2 
 6   l    e     .    3
```

SAS will throw errors or warnings if there are variable type conflicts.